# How do you transform coefficients from a linear regression on normalized data in Octave so they can be used with the un-normalized data?

Tags: regression, normalization

What I am currently doing is normalizing an input matrix, using linear regression with that normalized input data vs. the un-normalized output data, then trying to get the coefficients which should apply to the un-normalized input data.

(I am making the output the sum of each column so I know the resulting coefficients should all be ones)

```
input = rand(25, 3);
mu = mean(input);
sigma = std(input); 

input_norm = (input- mu)./sigma;

output = sum(input')';

coefficients_norm = LinearRegression(input_norm, output);
coefficients_expected = LinearRegression(input, output);



coefficients = (coefficients_norm).*sigma' + mu'
```

I do not see the coefficients variable as a vector of ones, but coefficients_expected is.

Am I correct in my inverse transform being the same transform to the normalized data to get back the original input data?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the original, non-normalized raw data?

Comment: The data itself is proprietary, I have tested this method both on that data and on a set of random data.

Comment: [This post on datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/49765/67328) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following, assuming that my normalized input times my normalized coefficients equals my normalized inputs times the coefficients (input * coefficients = input_norm * coefficients_norm), works.

```
coefficients = inv(input'*input)*input'*input_norm*coefficients_norm
```